# Android listview

Tags: android

Any one can help me in listview the first item should be selected by default

```
package com.globalscholar.announcement;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

import com.globalscholar.R;

public class PublishAnnouncement extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener, OnItemClickListener{
    private ListView lViewPub;
    private String lv_items[] = {"Teachers" , "Students", "Administration"};
    RadioButton radioSSP;
    RadioButton radioPubAll1;
    Button backPub;
    Button donePub;
    int role = 0;

    //venkat
    int selectedPublishOption = -1;
    AudienceWrapper audienceDetails = null; 

    ArrayList<Boolean> checkedStates = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    boolean checkedArray[];

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.publishannouncement);

    backPub=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttPubBack);
    backPub.setOnClickListener(this);

    donePub=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttPubDone);
    donePub.setOnClickListener(this);

    radioSSP=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioPubSSM);
    radioSSP.setOnClickListener(this);

    radioPubAll1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioPubAll);
    radioPubAll1.setOnClickListener(this);
    radioPubAll1.setChecked(true);


    lViewPub = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    lViewPub.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    //  Set option as Multiple Choice. So that user can be able to select more the one option from list
    lViewPub.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.announcementlistviewstyle, lv_items));
    lViewPub.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    lViewPub.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    getListView().setSelection(0);
    //venkat
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

    checkedStates.add(0, false);
    checkedStates.add(1, false);
    checkedStates.add(2, false);

    if(b!= null){
        audienceDetails = (AudienceWrapper) b.getSerializable("audienceDetails");
        selectedPublishOption = b.getInt("selectedPublishOption");
        //  checked = b.getLongArray("selectedPublishOptionsList");
        checkedArray =b.getBooleanArray("selectedPublishOptionsList");
        if(checkedArray!=null){
            Log.d("PA","Bundle Checked Array Size :"+checkedArray.length);
            for(int i=0;i<checkedArray.length;i++){
                checkedStates.set(i, checkedArray[i]);
                Log.w("PA","CheckedStatus index:"+i+"Status"+checkedStates.get(i));
                if(checkedStates.get(i))
                    lViewPub.setItemChecked(i, true);
            }
        }

        Log.d("selected publishoption in PublishAnnouncement--->", selectedPublishOption+"");
        if(selectedPublishOption == 0){
            radioPubAll1.setChecked(false);
            radioSSP.setChecked(true);
            lViewPub.setVisibility(BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            //for checking the options                  
        }
    }
    //venkatend
    PublishAnnouncement.this.getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
}



public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
        long arg3) {        
    Log.d("onItemClick position in PublishAnnouncement----->",position+"");
    //role value updated in wrong way when u double click on Item
    //solved role problem in done button
    /* if(position == 0){
         role+= 4;
     }
     else if(position == 1){
         role+=8;
     }
     else if(position == 2){
         role+=2;
     }else{
         role+=14;
     }  
     Log.d("PA","Role :"+role);*/

    //venkat for selected publishes
    boolean currentlyChecked = checkedStates.get(position);  
    checkedStates.set(position, !currentlyChecked); 
    if(checkedArray!=null)
        checkedArray[position] = !currentlyChecked;



}

public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.radioPubSSM:
        lViewPub.setVisibility(BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        break;
    case R.id.buttPubBack:
        onKeyDown(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK, 
                new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));
        break;
    case R.id.buttPubDone:
        //venkat
        int allSelect = 0;
        int sppCount=0;
        //venkatend
        Intent newPubDone= new Intent(PublishAnnouncement.this,Audience.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        if(radioPubAll1.isChecked()){
            role = 14;
            //venkat
            allSelect = 1;
        }else if(radioSSP.isChecked()){
            int len = checkedStates.size();     
            if(checkedArray == null)
                checkedArray = new boolean [len];
            for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
                checkedArray[i] = checkedStates.get(i);
                if(checkedStates.get(i)==true){
                    sppCount++;
                }
            }
            Log.d("PA","Count :"+sppCount);
        }
        if(sppCount==0 && radioSSP.isChecked()){
            AlertDialog.Builder alertBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alertBox.setMessage("Please select Specific Memebers");
            alertBox.setNeutralButton("Ok", null);
            alertBox.show();

        }else{
            b.putInt("SelectedPublishOption", allSelect);
            int finalRole = 0;
            if(allSelect== 0){
                // b.putLongArray("SelectedPublishOptionsList", checked);
                b.putBooleanArray("SelectedPublishOptionsList", checkedArray);
                if(checkedArray!=null){
                    if(checkedArray[0]){
                        finalRole+=4;
                    }
                    if(checkedArray[1]){
                        finalRole+=8;
                    }
                    if(checkedArray[2]){
                        finalRole+=2;
                    }
                }
                Log.d("PA","After selecting final Role Value :"+finalRole);
                if(audienceDetails!=null)
                    audienceDetails.setRoleValue(finalRole);

            }
            b.putInt("role", finalRole);
            //venkatend
            newPubDone.putExtras(b);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, newPubDone);
            System.out.println("Role value is" + role);
            finish();

        }
        break;
    case R.id.radioPubAll:
        lViewPub.setVisibility(-1);

        //venkat testing logic
        if(checkedArray!=null){
            int len= checkedArray.length;
            if(len > 0){
                for(int i=0;i<len;i++){                             
                    lViewPub.setItemChecked(i, false);
                    System.out.println("all selected Position selected "+checkedArray[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
}
```

thanks

Comment: so you want first item selected or not?

Comment: s i want first item to be selected as teacher getListView().setItemChecked(0, true); i gave list these but validation is not comming for me

Comment: Sry frnd actually what i want is there is a listview in that by default teacher should be selected,i have done these by using lViewPub.setItemChecked(0,true); these but even if its selected also validation message occurs –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use:

```
    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setFocusable(true);
    lv.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    lv.setSelection(0);
```

Comment: if i select teacher and click on done button also validation occurs

Comment: setSelection sets the currently selected item. If in touch mode, the item will not be selected but it will still be positioned appropriately. So it is not selected because your list is in touch mode, so use  lViewPub.setFocusable(true); first

Comment: and this too  lViewPub.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

Comment: Also change the checkedStates.add(0, false); to checkedStates.add(0, true);

Comment: Sry frnd actually what i want is there is a listview in that by default teacher should be selected,i have done these by using lViewPub.setItemChecked(0,true); these but even if its selected also validation message occurs

Comment: your problem in the validation condition  if(sppCount==0 && radioSSP.isChecked())   sppCount is not incremented by default so always sppCount == 0

Comment: --> Make the default sppCpunt = 1; and decrement it if teacher was unchecked, or --> make a a function that pass by all the checkboxes and update that count by the number of checked ones,, call the method on application entry and on change of any item in the list